# How to respond a Rails request within a configurable timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thread-safety, timeout

I want to achieve the following behavior in my controllers' action without the usage of Timeout module:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  def example
    Timeout.timeout(params[:timeout].to_i) do
      ... # try to process the request within params[:timeout] seconds
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error
    render nothing: true, status: :gateway_timeout
  end
end
```

I want to avoid the usage of Timeout because it's causing many bugs in my application, including database connection leaks. Some other problems reported at:
http://www.mikeperham.com/2015/05/08/timeout-rubys-most-dangerous-api/

Comment: what are you actually doing in this request? A timeout is a poor solution to a bigger problem - you may be able to preprocess or convert some of that code into a job, or even split a request into multiple stages with a state machine.

Comment: @court3nay It's a web service that runs jobs which may take from 100ms to 30 seconds to be processed. Each client can specify their own acceptable timeouts for the requested jobs.

Comment: @barbolo your current code has a flaw. It is best to wrap the timeout inside a `begin` block, followed by `rescue => e`. What re you trying to achieve? Stopping a request if the query takes too long?

Comment: The code is wrapped in a "try/catch" construction, I just didn't use begin.

Comment: I want to stop the request if it takes too long. Yes. But "too long" should be configurable.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use ruby for this. The problem is that the timeout module is going to abort the code somewhere, anywhere in your executing code, which is going to result in open and dangling sockets, connections and files or worse. (This isn't really a problem if you're firing up an external script or shelling out for each job, I guess, but in those cases just use the unix/linux native io timeout)

This is pretty much why ruby CI servers never took off (Jenkins is java).
I'd design this with a separate service that handles running jobs that you can ping with an API; then, in your view, ping it every few seconds so they can see continual updates. The rails app in this case wouldn't need to have any polluting timeout code in it.

edit: since you're doing HTTP requests in that block, just use the timeout setting built into the http library (e.g. https://github.com/lostisland/faraday )

Comment: Thank you, @court3nay. I hope to approve an answer with a solution in pure Ruby. Let's see what I get.

Comment: It dispatches a web scraper.

Comment: oh, see that's much easier. (why didn't you say so! heh) Most http libraries actually have a timeout setting in them. For example,
  https://github.com/lostisland/faraday has a connection AND request timeout setting per-request.

Comment: see also net/http http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html which has open_timeout, read_timeout, ssl_timeout and others; and http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/HTTParty/ClassMethods which has just one :timeout but the class can be overridden.

Comment: Well, that's not a solution for my problem. The task is a bit more complex than that. You can imagine that I may make 3 or 4 HTTP requests and Database operations for each web service request I receive. So, setting a Timeout for each I/O operation doesn't seem applicable.

Comment: the problem is that Timeout won't work in ruby reliably because it will break in random places in the stack of your app's code, and will break your app; your db connections will be in unknown states, maybe open or closed, class variables will leak, tempfiles open and not removed, etc; it's the worst of thread unsafety bugs. It removes the statelessness of your app.
So you can make a separate process you can call with http (you can indeed put a timeout on that) so that if/when that process times out, it doesn't break your main app's db connections and leave things in bad states.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `gem "rack-timeout"` https://github.com/heroku/rack-timeout for full fill your requirement.

```
# Gemfile

gem "rack-timeout"

# config/initializers/rack_timeout.rb
Rack::Timeout.timeout = 5  # seconds
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: That's actually a pretty good gem, but doesn't solve my problem. It doesn't allow me to specify the timeout per request. It expects a fixed value for the timeout specified during application initialization.